# c++: Catch runtime_error

Tags: c++, exception, runtime-error

I am learning c++ at home and I am using the rapidxml lib.
I am using the utils provided with it to open files:

```
rapidxml::file<char> myfile (&filechars[0]);
```

I noticed that if `filechars` is wrong the `rapidxml::file` throw a runtime_error:

```
// Open stream
basic_ifstream<Ch> stream(filename, ios::binary);
if (!stream)
  throw runtime_error(string("cannot open file ") + filename);
stream.unsetf(ios::skipws);
```

I think I need to write something like that:

```
try
{
  rapidxml::file<char> GpxFile (pcharfilename);
}
catch ???
{
   ???
}
```

I made some googling, but I did not find what I need in the place of the `???`.

Could somebody help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to add an exception declaration next to the `catch` statement. The type thrown is [std::runtime_error](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/stdexcept/runtime_error/).

```
try
{
  rapidxml::file<char> GpxFile (pcharfilename);
}
catch (const runtime_error& error)
{
   // your error handling code here
}
```

If you need to catch multiple, different kinds of exceptions, then you can tack on more than one `catch` statement:

```
try
{
  rapidxml::file<char> GpxFile (pcharfilename);
}
catch (const runtime_error& error)
{
   // your error handling code here
}
catch (const std::out_of_range& another_error)
{
   // different error handling code
}
catch (...)
{
   // if an exception is thrown that is neither a runtime_error nor
   // an out_of_range, then this block will execute
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. I was missing the type of the exception and its usage in the catch block. So if well understood, I will try: `catch( const runtime_error& error ) { cout << error.what() << endl; }`.

Answer (score 10):

```
try
{
    throw std::runtime_error("Hi");
}
catch(std::runtime_error& e)
{
   cout << e.what() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it conforms the usage of what()!

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on what you want to do when it happens.  This is the minimum:

```
try
{
  rapidxml::file<char> GpxFile (pcharfilename);
}
catch (...)
{
   cout << "Got an exception!"
}
```

If you want to get at the actual exception, then you need to declare a variable to store it in inside the parentheses in place of the three dots.

Comment: Indeed I was missing the type of the exception.